# Why does the View know about the Model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have done some work on ASP.NET MVC 3 but I'm no expert.

So, based on the pattern definition, the view has no direct awareness of the model and does not communicate with the model directly; only controller is directly dealing with model.

However, in ASP.NET MVC 3, I can access the  model data directly from the view using Razor engine. Isn't that breaking the pattern design or am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps what you meant is Model View Controller ? Could you provide a link that says so ?

Comment: The view has no control _over_ the model, but is aware of it. What would you build/display if you didn't know how the model looks like?

Comment: i updated the question..can anybody explain the connection between model and view in this pattern..as far as i know view can manipulate data through controller only..or i read it wrong??

Comment: @AfterGlow in proper MVC the view would be requesting data from model layer. So, yes, it would be extremely aware of it. The dumbed down description would be: *controller writes, view reads.* But that's not how ASP.NET MVC has been implemented.

Answer (score 4):

> the view has no direct awareness of the model and do not communicate with the model directly

Not exactly. Exactly how to interpret this statement might depend on the reader.

I've read quite a bit on [model-view-controller](/questions/tagged/model-view-controller) and [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) and I find similar statements scattered around and so the way it's worded can be a bit confusing.

A **view** knows what the **model** is. That is, it should know what the model type is, what the model contains or by some means know how to use the model to display what is necessary.

If we have a page called `UserProfile` then the view knows that it should display the user's name, email address, age and favourite website.

The view might be told to expect a `UserProfileViewModel`. Such a class would contain exactly the properties that the view needs so that it can easily display them.

What is better to say is that the view should not *modify* the model. In fact, the view should not **do** much of anything. Views are supposed to be stupid - they aren't for processing business rules, modifying data, connecting to databases, and so on. They just display stuff.

Comment: how "A view knows what the model is. "..actually controller is supplying model to view right?..like 'return view(model)' .then view is connected to model only though controller right?

Comment: Yes. A view is given a model object by the controller.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC seems a lot closer to Rails then it is to proper MVC.

Answer (score 1):

The model **contains** the data, the controller **manipulates** the data and the view **displays** the data (model). The view therefore is the interaction with the user.

The view must know what to show, so it has the model (with its data) to do so. It never manipulates directly, but sends information to the controller which in turn will manipulate the data.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have mistaken the concept of **MVC**. **MVC** does not say that "View is not aware of Model". In practice, each view is tightly coupled with a model (unless view is coupled to dynamic model or base type).

MVC is actually separation of concerns.

1. **Controller** decides the business rule and decides what data to be shown to user.
2. Then it populates the **Model**.
3. Then pass on the **Model** to **View**. (Think of it like passing on some data to be displayed on view).
4. Now **View** is not aware how **model** is created and **validation** rules of model.
5. **Model** is not aware which **view** will consume it. There can be many views coupled to a model.
6. **Controller** is not aware of model validation or what property of model is being displayed on view.

And MVC is just a pattern to follow, it does not stop you from writing business logic inside view or make db calls from view.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this article](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/the-three-models-of-asp.net-mvc-apps/) to read about the three different types of "models" introduced by ASP.NET MVC.

What it sounds like you are referring to is the *view* model. This model is simply a container or a way provide structure around the data that the view is responsible for displaying. It is simply a data-transfer object (does not have any behavior).